# Rapsberry Pi Zero serial receiving too much data from packet

Tags: serial

I have a python program that reads data from a USB serial port connected to a computer. The computer sends data packets from a simulation program (I didn't write this).

The data is made of strings of no more than 200 bytes serially with 21 data fields separated by commas at a baud rate of 115200 with 8N1.

In the python program, I have:

```
ser = serial.Serial(port=PORTNAME, baudrate=115200, timeout=.02)
while True:
    # OTHER STUFF IS IN THE LOOP AS WELL THAT DOESN'T HAVE TO DO WITH THE SERIAL
    time.sleep(0.01)
    data = ser.read(200)
```

Most of the time, the `data` will be exactly 21 fields, but sometimes the `data` variable will be a string that has one entire data packet as well as the beginning of the next one appended to it, and the function that parses each individual data field will obviously return an exception.

Something I tried just for fun is adding a lot of print statements in the loop, which made the exception in the program happen significantly faster. I think it might have to do with the time.

Does anyone know how I can fix this? If not, I can just hard code a hack in the function that parses the `data`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have gone with a default of no flow control, and you have also specified no parity bits.

Do you have control over the communications parameters on both sides? I know you said you didn't write the PC side but do you have the ability to specify port settings such as baud rate, parity bit, flow control?

If so, I would try turning on hardware flow control and perhaps even or odd parity even though it is not going to provide much protection.

See the third example [here.](http://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shortintro.html)

It's the "parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN, rtscts=1" part that I am suggesting, but of course you have to be able to make the same change on both sides.

p.s. In my opinion, you should still be doing what I think you're calling a hack ;-) which is to look at the data received and make sure it adheres to the expected format.

Comment: Unfortunately, the simulation is just a representation of something that's going to happen in real life, where I would not be able to change the settings on the computer. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: You might still try turning on rtscts=1. It's possible the PC side is already using it. If you turn it on and the PC side is not using it, all that's going to happen is if your side attempts to flow control the session the other side will ignore it and data loss could occur, similar to what your seeing now occasionally. If it doesn't help, put your code back the old way.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned any delimiter that is used to signal the end of a message, and therein lies your problem. Typically comma-delimited data uses a newline ('\n') to mark the end of a data block, and your software needs to detect that, which can be done with the serial readline function.

If you are unlucky, and a different delimiter is used, then you need to keep filling a buffer with the input data until the delimiter is detected, then return the buffer to your analysis function, and clear it out ready to start the next block.

If you are really unlucky, and there is no delimiter, you have to parse the whole message as you suggest, or use the dead-time between messages to determine that a block has finished - this is probably do-able (if there is a significant gap), but a bit tricky to get right; it is much better to have a unique end-of-block marker.